# Python FTP how to ask for folders and delete/remove and create new one

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp

So I'm looking for a script to connect to my FTP server and ask for folders and delete/remove those folders and make new ones after the delete/remove. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ftplib` is built into Python and should do exactly what you need. It is well documented here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ftplib.html

You'll need to use `ftp.rmd(dir)` to remove a directory and `ftp.mkd(dir)` to create one. Here's are some commands you might use:

```
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP('ftp.example.com')
ftp.login()

# List contents
ftp.dir()

# Or get file/folder names
items = ftp.nlst()

# Delete directory 'mydir'
ftp.rmd('mydir')

# Create directory 'mydir'
ftp.mkd('mydir')

# Disconnect
ftp.quit()
```

Comment: `ftp.rmd` does not work if the directory is not empty. Any ideas or third-party libs that are more convenient to use?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the ftplib, something like with this:

```
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP(your_host)
ftp.login(user=your_username, passwd=your_password)
```

To get a single file from your ftp instance, use

```
`ftp.retrbinary('RETR {}'.format(file_name), destination)`
```

A delete just uses `ftp.delete(file_name)`, sends use

`ftp.storbinary('STOR {}'.format(file_name), source)`

and lists can use `ftp.nlst()`

Comment: I'm actually trying to connect and immediatly remove/delete folders empty or full so that will not work with ftp.delete :/ .